# Explicit Casting Generic to Another Type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting, explicit

I have the following code for C++, in a templated class that represents a point. I would like to translate it into C#:

```
template <class T>
class Point
{
    public:
        T x;
        T y;
        T z;

    template<typename U> explicit Point(const Point<U> &p)
       : x((T)p.x), y((T)p.y), z((T)p.z)
    {
    }
}
```

This code enables a point of a given type to be explicitly cast into a point of another type. For example, you may use it something like (admittedly I am not 100% sure on the syntax here, but I get the concept):

```
Point<float> p;
Point<int> q = (Point<int>)p;
```

How could I enable the equivalent to this in C#? So far I have:

```
public class Point<T>
{
    public T X { get; set; }
    public T Y { get; set; }
    public T Z { get; set; }

    // Constructors exist that accept X, Y, and Z as parameters

    public static explicit operator Point<U>(Point<T> p)
    {

    }
}
```

This gives an error, however, saying "U" is undefined. This makes sense... but how/where do I define U? Is my approach incorrect?

The difference between my question and the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767192/defining-explicit-casting-for-generic-types-in-c-sharp) is that I am simply changing the underlaying type of the generic class via a cast... not trying to change one generic class into a different generic class with the same underlaying type.

Comment: Conversion operators can't be generic..

Comment: Do you need `U` as a generic parameter? You can replace `U` with an actual type. Granted, you'd only have a limited number of conversion types you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you can get is this:

```
public class Point<T>
{
    public T X { get; set; }
    public T Y { get; set; }
    public T Z { get; set; }

    public Point<U> As<U>()
    {
        return new Point<U>()
        {
            X = Convert<U>(X),
            Y = Convert<U>(Y),
            Z = Convert<U>(Z)
        };
    }

    static U Convert<U>(T t) => (U)System.Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(U));
}
```

You cannot define a generic conversion operator, so you need it to be an explicit function. Moreover, a simple cast `(U)t` won't work, so you need `Convert.ChangeType` (which will work if your types are numeric).

Usage:

```
var p1 = new Point<int> { X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3 };
var p2 = p1.As<double>();
```

([works as expected](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAIGYAEqBMmAKA9gJZTAA8AKgHwCwAUAN4OavZaWYAamjmA5gFNgAbkwBnYWIC+LNhkycAmrwFSJ62fTbtFmAFqqhojSa1zWCoqQoBVapgCC48vYAUASgu9vO1AHZMKEEAdwISMldqT182Zm0dRNYeAF5MAGFCKAA3QTA7aK4PGFiklTTMnLyCtyVi0sTDCqzc/Ki3fS8EpOkRb3Nu7ABGADZMWwyW6vbOYA9MFIc3Ww9UIYA6StbgTYALAEMoIUoATwAHQTdgGExgc8FCADNljw8++gHcYf8GeL9R7AAFkwAFl9qQYoM/klMNl9mBMGchgsgqFwjZyDYHHxUpghjdypgcDcmpgsL0GnCEWc8GkketnOQ4IQIAAjAA2gmibwaa3WawAnG4ACQAIkYNPWXBAADkcNIbhKcOslLL5YrJfo1dJRTzBlppEA==)).

Comment: Note that `Convert.ChangeType` works only for types that implement `IConvertible`. Which is perfectly fine if OP sticks with primitive types

Comment: @KevinGosse: yes, I'm saying in my answer "which will work if your types are numeric". Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this kind of generic cast is only allowed in C# if there's some kind of inheritance relationship between `T` and `U`.

The closest equivalent would be to define a generic method for the conversion:

```
public Point<U> To<U>()
{
    dynamic p = this;

    return new Point<U>((U)p.X, (U)p.Y, (U)p.Z);
}
```

You cannot convert directly `T` to `U` as the compiler has no way to know whether it'll be safe. I use the `dynamic` keyword to bypass that restriction.

Comment: This appears to be more generic then, since it won't require numeric types. My problem happens to (only numeric types will be used)… but this is good to know for future if that is not the case. I do wonder what the performance difference is between this vs the `Convert.ChangeType` option.

Comment: @MichaelKintscher That's a good question. I ran a quick benchmark, I get 127ns for `Convert.ChangeType` vs 53ns for `Dynamic`. Note that the first call to dynamic is much more expensive (as the expression is evaluated during first invokation then cached)

Comment: Good to know! I also added `where U : IConvertible` as a constraint on both `T` and `U`, just to be safe for the consumer of my class.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54795214/64348), but without `dynamic` is to use a double cast:

```
public Point<U> To<U>()
{
    return new Point<U>((U)(object)X, (U)(object)Y, (U)(object)Z);
}
```

Both of our answers don't catch any issues at compile-time.

Comment: This won't work, you need to unbox the value before casting it. `int i = (int)(object)1.0f;`throws an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: Hm. Oh yeah you're right. I use the double-cast in a bunch of generic designs, but it's always been for reference types.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare operators with additional generic type arguments, but you can declare ones to or from specific generic types like `Point<int>`. C# will also not let you perform arbitrary conversions by casting from or to `T`.

The least boilerplate heavy option that maintains a modicum of type safety would be to constrain the `T` parameter to `IConvertible`:

```
public class Point<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    // ...

    public static explicit operator Point<int>(Point<T> point)
    {
        // The IFormatProvider parameter has no effect on purely numeric conversions
        return new Point<int>(point.X.ToInt32(null), point.Y.ToInt32(null), point.Y.ToInt32(null));
    }    
}
```

However, this will not prevent users from declaring nonsensical, unsupported types such as `Point<DateTime>` which will then throw at runtime when attempting a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define additional generic type constraints, but you can do something like this, using operators and methods.

```
public class Point<T>
{
    public T X { get; set; }
    public T Y { get; set; }
    public T Z { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Point<T>(Point<int> v)
    {
        return v.As<T>();
    }

    public static explicit operator Point<T>(Point<double> v)
    {
        return v.As<T>();
    }

    public static explicit operator Point<T>(Point<float> v)
    {
        return v.As<T>();
    }

    public Point<TU> As<TU>()
    {
        return new Point<TU>()
        {
            X = ConvertTo<TU>(X),
            Y = ConvertTo<TU>(Y),
            Z = ConvertTo<TU>(Z)
        };
    }

    private static TU ConvertTo<TU>(T t)
    {
        return (TU) Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(TU));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        Point<double> d = new Point<double>()
        {
            X = 10d, Y = 10d, Z = 10d
        };

        Point<int> i = (Point<int>) d;

        Point<float> f = (Point<float>) i;

        d = (Point<double>) f;
```